# hasOne() relationship can return many relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

The User model has a one to one relationship with the PhoneNumber class:

```
public function phoneNumber() {
    return $this->hasOne(PhoneNumber::class);
}
```

Yet, if the PhoneNumber table has multiple rows with the same user_id (for example 1), multiple models are returned from the Eloquent statement.

```
$multiplePhoneNumbers = User::find(1)->phoneNumber()->get();
```

This begs the question, what is the purpose of the `hasOne()` vs. `hasMany()` relationship?

Comment: One difference I noticed is if you use eager loading. hasOne() just returns 1 (the first match), hasMany() will return multiple.
---- $userModelWithOnePhoneNumber = User::with('phoneNumber')->find(1);

Answer (score 3):

`phoneNumber()` returns the query builder instance, to where you can append more methods like `where()` or `orderBy()` for example. Calling `get()` from that just executes the query without the added `hasOne` logic.

Behind the hood, the relationship will return the first result if you use it correctly.

`User::find(1)->phoneNumber` will return either a phone number or null.

Comment: You are correct. using find(1) and get() together was a mistake. also i should have known better than to use the relationship like a method ( phoneNumber() )